# Compose Family Hierarchy in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an used case that I am trying to solve in Oracle 12c. If someone can help with the solution then I will be very grateful. Many thanks in advance!

Input
**Family_ID Seq_ID  Name    Ref_Parent**  
55      1   John      
55      2   James   1  
55      3   Mary     2  
55      4   Jim 3  
65      5   Mark      
65      6   Gen 5  
65      7   Mary    6  
65      8   Jim 7

Expected Output  
**Family_ID Seq_ID  Name    Ref_Parent  Hierarchy**  
55  1   John        John  
55  2   James   1   John > James  
55  3   Mary    2   John > James > Mary  
55  4   Jim 3   John > James > Mary > Jim  
65  5   Mark        Mark  
65  6   Gen 5   Mark > Gen  
65  7   Mary    6   Mark > Gen > Mary  
65  8   Jim 7   Mark > Gen > Mary > Jim

Comment: Hint : `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`

Comment: Please provide CREATE (with PRIMARY/UNIQUE/FOREIGN keys) and INSERT statements.

Answer (score 3):

Using this schema (it might be wrong):

```
CREATE TABLE family (
  family_ID NUMBER,
  seq_ID NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(100),
  ref_parent NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (seq_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (ref_parent) REFERENCES family
);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (55, 1, 'John', NULL);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (55, 2, 'James', 1);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (55, 3, 'Mary', 2);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (55, 4, 'Jim', 3);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (65, 5, 'Mark', NULL);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (65, 6, 'Gen', 5);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (65, 7, 'Mary', 6);
INSERT INTO family VALUES (65, 8, 'Jim', 7);
```

The solution (based on [Kaushik Nayak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7998591/kaushik-nayak)'s comment) would be something like:

```
SELECT f.family_id, f.seq_id, f.name, f.ref_parent, SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(f.name, ' > '), 4) hierarchy
FROM family f
CONNECT BY PRIOR f.seq_id = f.ref_parent
START WITH f.ref_parent IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY f.seq_id
```

Output:

```
FAMILY_ID | SEQ_ID | NAME  | REF_PARENT | HIERARCHY
----------+--------+-------+------------+--------------------------
55        | 1      | John  | (null)     | John
55        | 2      | James | 1          | John > James
55        | 3      | Mary  | 2          | John > James > Mary
55        | 4      | Jim   | 3          | John > James > Mary > Jim
65        | 5      | Mark  | (null)     | Mark
65        | 6      | Gen   | 5          | Mark > Gen
65        | 7      | Mary  | 6          | Mark > Gen > Mary
65        | 8      | Jim   | 7          | Mark > Gen > Mary > Jim
```

See [Oracle docs on SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions164.htm) function and this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04d420/8/0), to see it working.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for big help here. As always feels great to learn something new.